# String format for binding text in WPF

Tags: wpf, data-binding, string-formatting

Say that I have a static text resource

```
public static string MainText = "Test: {0} Test2: {1}";
```

And I then want to use this text in WPF like this

```
<Label Content="x:Static ***.MainText" />
```

but bind two values to it, how do I do that?

Comment: I can add that I don't want to use Runs in a TextBlock since I want to keep the string as one string for translation.

Comment: You would use a `Converter` then. XAML can only go so far. And in YOur Binding you can also use `StringFormat` like so : `<Label Content="{Binding INPCProperty, StringFormat}"`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here are two ways you can do it, one with a converter and one without.

"Text1" and "Text2" in the bindings are properties of the DataContext.

You will need to change the "MainText" to be a property:

```
public static string MainText { get; set; } = "Test: {0} Test2: {1}";
```

Without a converter:

```
<Label>
    <Label.Content>
        <TextBlock>
            <TextBlock.Text>
                <MultiBinding StringFormat="{x:Static local:MainWindow.MainText}">
                    <Binding Path="Text1" />
                    <Binding Path="Text2" />
                </MultiBinding>
            </TextBlock.Text>
        </TextBlock>
    </Label.Content>
</Label>
```

With a converter:

```
<Label>
    <Label.Resources>
        <local:TextFormatConverter x:Key="TextFormatConverter" />
    </Label.Resources>
    <Label.Content>
        <MultiBinding Converter="{StaticResource TextFormatConverter}" ConverterParameter="{x:Static local:MainWindow.MainText}">
            <Binding Path="Text1" />
            <Binding Path="Text2" />
        </MultiBinding>
    </Label.Content>
</Label>
```

And the converter:

```
public class TextFormatConverter : IMultiValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object[] values, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        string fmt = parameter as string;
        if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(fmt))
            return string.Format(fmt, values);
        return null;
    }

    public object[] ConvertBack(object value, Type[] targetTypes, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

Comment: Ok, I can't change it to a property because of the way we've set up our translation unfortunately. I wanted to see if there were some other solution than using a converter, but I'll just go for that then. Thanks :)

Comment: You could pass something else in as the parameter that identifies the text - like, "MainText" and then use reflection or whatever you have to find the string format somehow (project specific).